# How do I stop my VPN from crashing every few minutes, sometimes as often as I can log back in?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

Each crash disrupts an instance I regularly work in, requires me to re-enter the lengthy password, and sometimes fails again as soon as I log back in. It is common for me to have to login 40 or 50 or more times in an evening. I do not have admin rights to my machine so I cannot run jobs behind the scene to clean whatever is being suggested on a dos prompt and I have used lots of VPN services from home (on this network) and never had this issue.